# How do you write a SWIG interface file for a function that uses vector<string>?

Tags: c++, python, swig

I have a c++ file that I want to turn into a Python module using SWIG. This file consists of a single function `vector<string> load(string input) {`. I am, of course, using the c++ headers `<vector>` and `<string>`. Ideally, I want this function to return a Python list when called from Python. Unfortunately, I have relatively little experience with SWIG, and I was wondering what the easiest way to do this is. I read about using %include "std_string.i" and %include "std_vector.i" in the interface file, but so far, I have only figured out how to use std_vector to handle `vector<int>` or `vector<double>` and such, but not `vector<string>`. There must be a way to do it though. I was just wondering if someone could explain to me how. I'm using SWIG 2.0.7 on Mac OsX 10.7.4 with Python 2.7.1.

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469138/swig-wrapping-c-for-python-translating-a-list-of-strings-to-an-stl-vector-of?rq=1

Comment: Or this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11219110/235698

Comment: Thanks, those did clear things up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what I do:

```
%include "stl.i"
%template(_string_list) std::vector< std::string >;
```